# python simple loop_.join function

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm an amateur learner and would like to have more ideas on these.

This is what I want,

paper_doll('Hello') --> 'HHHeeellllllooo'

Here is my code and it doesn't work, but I have no ideas why.

```
def paper_doll(text):
for i in range(0,len(text)-1):
    return ''.join(text[i]*3)
paper_doll('Hello')
```

The result became 'HHH'.

Understood the following would work,
    def paper_doll(text):
    result = ''
    for char in text:
        result += char * 3
    return result

But why .join doesn't work in this case?

Comment: It works, but you leave the loop with `return` after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
def paper_doll(text):
    ret=[]
    for i in text:
       ret.append(i*3)
    return ''.join(ret)
```

Should work. This returns each 3 letter iteration, joined together.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial problem was the `return` in your iteration. This short circuits the rest of the loop... as noted in other answers.

python can iterate through a string for you. Another answer using list comprehension:

```
def paper_doll(text):
   return ''.join([char*3 for char in text])
```

Comment: Or a generator expression: `return ''.join(char*3 for char in text)`

Comment: @FredLarson It's slightly more efficient to pass a list to `join`, due to how the iterator protocol works. (`join` has to scan the entire input before it can allocate a string object big enough to hold the result, and a list comprehension is faster than `join` having to consume an arbitrary iterable).

Comment: @chepner: News to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, your code does not work because the return statement exits from the function on the first iteration loop, so it triples only the first letter, and that's all:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    for i in range(0,len(text)-1): # on 1st iteration: i = 0
        return ''.join(text[i]*3)  # on 1st iteration: text[i] equals 'H' ==> 'HHH' is returned
```

Secondly, here is a solution using comprehension, which is well adapted in your case to iterate over each character of a string:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    return ''.join(i*3 for i in text)

print(paper_doll('Hello'))   # HHHeeellllllooo
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to a string during the loop, return the result:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    s = ''
    for i in range(0,len(text)):
        s += ''.join(text[i]*3)
    return s

print(paper_doll('Hello'))
```

Output:

```
HHHeeellllllooo
```

(I also removed the `-1` in `range` so you get three "o"s)

Comment: thanks. But is there any reason behind? guess the main issue is +=, in which accumulate the result from text[0], text[1], text[2] and so on? is that true?

Comment: There's no reason to use `+=` *and* `join`; `''.join(x)` is equivalent to `x` if `x` is a string.

Comment: Yes, thats true. Btw I got a downvote probably because thats not the way you should do it. However it might help you understand the problem.

Comment: I downvoted because it's grossly inefficient and is a terrible example of how to write Python code, not because it failed to reach some Pythonic ideal.

Comment: @chepner the poster said "I have no ideas why". Now he has an idea why. that was the objective, not to write efficient code.

Comment: @jonas thanks a lot...no matter what. Learn a lot from you guys